# crontab entry to reboot than email

Tags: email, cron, notification

I got my weekly crontab reboot entry to work using `/sbin/shutdown -r` but now I want it to email me when the reboot happens. Ideally I would like the email to happen after it rebooted so I know the server came up okay.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To send an email from a script or from command line you can use `mail`:

```
echo "message" | mail -s "subject" "email@example.com"
```

Notice that for this to work, you have to install a **mail transport agent (MTA)** (for example `sendmail`):

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

To execute this at every **bootup** you can write a line in your crontab as follows:

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

Comment: I have ssmtp installed on the system. Is that a acceptable MTA?

Comment: Should do the job, try the mail command above, you will see an error if it does not work.

Comment: I tried the echo "message".... command you suggested and got this "The program mail is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install mailutils"

Comment: You answered your own question, install it with: `sudo apt-get install mailutils`